# How to set cron in to run PHP file on localhost in Ubuntu?

Tags: php, ubuntu, cron

I want to execute a PHP script on my localhost in Ubuntu. I have tried a lots of methods to apply cron but no luck!

Answer (score 3):

We can set cron on our localhost through following steps:

1. Open crontab in your terminal:

   ```
   EDITOR=gedit crontab -e
   ```
2. Add your cron settings at the end of your file (we are setting cron to be execute in every 2 minute in our example):

   ```
   */2 * * * * /usr/bin/php -q /path/to/phpfile.php > /dev/null
   ```
3. Save your cron file and run:

   ```
   sudo service cron restart
   ```

Comment: I don't think you need to restart the cron service. As far as I know, `crontab` installs the new schedules as soon as you exit your editor.